# Using pointPolyTest to 'mask out' a polygon-ROI OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an outer contour approximated `CV::approxPoyDP()` function called the `approxPolygon`. Now, I want to 'mask out' another image, `edge`, using this approximated contour. The idea is to find all pixels outside this "approximated contour" and reset the pixel value to 0. This way all region outside the desired ROI is black.

But I am having trouble with using the function `CV::pointPolyTest();`. When I try to loop through the image to return a bool value to see if a given point is inside or outside the given approximated contour, the function always returns `false`.

This is part of my code.

```
segments = ImageSegment::Image[7];
edge = ImageSegment::detectEdges(segments);
```

edge is the image which needs to be masked out using the contour 'approxPolygon'.

```
  for (int row; row <= edge.rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col; col < edge.cols; col++)
        {
            if(!pointPolygonTest(approxPolygon, Point2f(float(row), float(col)), false))
            {
                edge.at<float>(row,col) = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason, the output of this code sets all pixels of edge to zero, essentially a blacked out image. Whats wrong in my code? Does the `CV::pointPolyTest()` work as documented? Thank you.

Comment: Just create a mask drawing your polygon (use fillPoly), and then use setTo with the inverse of this mask

Comment: @Miki Thanks bro :)